# simple c# regex example

Tags: c#, regex

I am searching through a database schema text file where all stored procedures, functions, triggers and views are delimited by ";;". I am splitting the contents on the ";;" delimiter and then for each piece, looking for "CREATE PROCEDURE", "CREATE FUNCTION", "CREATE TRIGGER" or "CREATE VIEW". However, this search criteria could not be as perfect as I just listed. For example, "CREATE PROCEDURE" could be: "create PROCEDURE", "create procedure", "CREATE    PROCEDURE", etc.

This looks like a pretty simple regex pattern to check for but I am new to regex and struggling a bit. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Post the code you've written so far.

Comment: Have you tried using `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` already?

Comment: Use a case insensitive modifier in the regex you made.

Answer (score 2):

```
var regex = new Regex(@"\bcreate\s+(procedure|function|view|trigger)" + 
                      @"\s+(?<ObjectName>[a-z_][a-z0-9_]+)\b", 
                      RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Comment: I need to create a token based on the match so I need to differentiate between procedure, function, view or trigger.

Comment: Also, it didn't show up in my question but there could be one or more spaces or tabs between "create" and "procedure", for example.

Comment: I think I have it?

var myRegex = new Regex(@"create\s*procedure", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

Comment: Yes, you can also add ``\b`` before ``create`` and ``procedure``.  


@"\bcreate\s*procedure\b"